# Drupal adding multiple directories to URLs creating duplicate content

Tags: 7, uri

I have a Drupal 7 site that is creating a seemingly infinite stream of sub-directories creating a vast amount of duplicate content. For example:

example.com/test/ - is a legitimate page.

example.com/test/test/ - is a duplicate of the above, and this goes on and on like so:

example.com/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test/test - etc etc.

All of these pages are crawlable and returning a 200 code. I'm not very familiar with Drupal and I can't pinpoint what is causing this. Any ideas?

Many thanks.